# What is the difference between the Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll and the Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Intl.dll

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When I attempt to make a reference to the SharePoint Taxonomy DLL there are 2 versions of it that appear.  Both have the title Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy but the file names are difference.  Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.DLL and What is the difference between the Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Intl.dll.

I am curious what the Intl stands for and what the purpose of the Dll is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Intl.dll` assembly  is intended for storing resource files. 
I guess in SharePoint `Intl` is used as a naming convention for [satellite assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht(v=vs.110).aspx).

To summarize, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Intl.dll` provides  access to  resources at run time for `Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll` assembly via [ResourceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Do you know what the Intl stands for??

Comment: I guess Intl means International